# set the default value of textbox based on value in another textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have two textbox say txt1 and txt2. I want to set default value of txt2 as same as txt1. Is thr any way to do it in aspx file. user should also able to change the value of txt2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this by .blur().

Have a look here

```
$("#txt1").blur(function() { 
  $("#txt2").val($("#txt1").val());
});
```

For more information on blur [CLICK HERE](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve that,

what you mean by default value?
if you want all the value in txt1 in txt2 ? then below code may work for you.
if     txt1 and txt2  are asp:TextBox then you have to use ClientID

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input[id$=txt1 ]').keyup(function() {
var txtClone = $(this).val();
$('input[id$=txt2]').val(txtClone);
});
});
</script>
```